# get Error: 'no module named 'matplotlib.style' while matplotlib works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm on an ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with python3. I want to use the 'ggplot' style module, but I get an 'no module named' error. Matplotlib 1.3.1 is installed and works fine (I updated it recently).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.style as mplstyle
mplstyle.use('ggplot')

ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.style'
```

I also checked for the matplotlibrc file and matplotlibtool and everything seems to be as the documentation recommends. Anyone knows, what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [What's new in matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#style-package-added), the `style` package was added to matplotlib since version 1.4.

So, check your matplotlib version by,

```
$ pip freeze | grep matplotlib
matplotlib==1.3.1
```

Upgrade matplotlib to the newest version by,

```
$ sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade

$ pip freeze | grep matplotlib
matplotlib==1.5.1
```

This works fine for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

Comment: I needed to upgrade the libfreetype6 first by `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` and after that update it in pycharm of course. But then it works fine. thanks a lot.